# Spring security: all of a sudden my UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken turns into AnonymousAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Like the title says... 
I am using Spring security and sometimes when I am called in my PermissionEvaluator to:

```
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication inAuthentication, Serializable inTargetId, String inTargetType, Object inPermission) {
```

Instead of getting in the Authentication a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken I get an instance of AnonymousAuthenticationToken.

If it can be of any use the AnonymousAuthenticationToken contains:

- Principal: anonymousUser
- Credentials: PROTECTED
- Authenticated: true

I have no clue how this can happen. No exceptions in the logs. Any ideas?

Comment: Do enable the trace / debug logs for spring and analyse, there would surely be hint to it. The information provided herewith is too less for us to help.

Comment: It basically means your user is not authenticated and thus it's anonymous. Are you sure there is an authenticated user when the method is called?

Comment: @ Bond, Tks for your reply. We have only noticed this effect in the productive system and rarely. It's not going to be easy to convince the customer to allow us setting his system into debug. I was just hopping someone could have already run into the same issue.

Comment: @ NeilsNet. Tks for your reply. We have a correctly logged in user, and suddenly the Authentication is switched into the anonymous one. I know this is so because the user is doing operations that require calls to hasPermission and inside this method we cast the Authentication.getPrincial to UserDetails. All is fine until all the calls for this user start throwing exceptions because the getPrincipal returns String with 'anonymousUser'